# MVC 4 Client side validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Trying to learn the basics of ASP.net MVC and cant quite understand why my client side validation isnt working.

I have this in both my web.config files (1 is global 1 is in the views folder)

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I have this in my _layout.cshtmlfile

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
```

This is my view model for which im testing registration:

```
public class RegisterVM
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Username Required")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Password Required")]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Compare("password", ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match")]
        public string passwordConfirm { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my html

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm()){

    @Html.LabelFor( model => model.username)
    @Html.EditorFor( model => model.username)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.username)<br />

    @Html.LabelFor( model => model.password)
    @Html.PasswordFor( model => model.password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.password)<br />

    @Html.LabelFor( model => model.passwordConfirm)
    @Html.EditorFor( model => model.passwordConfirm)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.passwordConfirm)<br />

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />


}
```

Didn't want to post here, ive read a few topics on here related but cant seem to fix my issues, when i click submit it's making post/get requests.

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but is the order of files loaded in ` _layout.cshtmlfile` correct? didn't you missed a js from the first statement, and did you checked the files that has been loaded in browser?

Comment: View source shows all the files are loaded.

Comment: Did u try loading validate.min.js before validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Comment: Yes, the order is wrong. Unobtrusive validation depends on jQuery Validate.

Comment: Fixed, my god spent so long wasting time on this wondering what on earth was wrong, wish I swallowed my pride an just asked!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Feels like *this should work*, I think you need to load validate.min.js before validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Comment: Already covered, that was the answer but comments above cant be marked as correct! Thanks

Comment: Yep I commented above but then realized that as answer it could be helpful for others

Comment: Hello, in my view file I set to layout=null and added the order of scripts <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") But the client script is not working, appreciate if you can tell me what else i need to modify? or suggestions. thank you

Comment: i also tried using jquery-1.7.1.min.js instead of 2.1.0 but still client side validation is not working, is there maybe a specific version I should be using?

Comment: In my case, I noticed some time scaffolding skips adding @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") at the end of layout file, I added it manually and it works.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and the only thing that fixed it was to manually call

```
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

before I press the submit button.

I finally put it in document ready callback.

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
});
```

Comment: After trying a lot of solutions without success, this one works very good. Thanks

Comment: I noticed this issue after bundling my scripts in BundleConfig.cs and my call to `$('#nameOfForm').validate();` wasn't working. Once i added this line it started working so thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

In your page you have these two line in bottom of the page

***please See carefully***

```
@section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you doesn't load jquery.validate.min.js before the unobtrusive one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divParent').load("url",
                     function () {
                     $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));}
                );
```

Note: This is required if you are loading 'form' or 'PartialView' dynamically inside 'div' using ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

You need just reference these files on every page you need validation my friend!

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```