# Not able to display error message in Dropdownlist In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am really stuck here for a long time and I don't know why its not working. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729440/validate-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc) where it explained how to implement validation in MVC. But not working for me.

My problem is I am able to display list in drop down but it is not showing any error message when I am in default option which was supposed to display error message.

**My code is show below :**

**Model class :**

```
public class ValidationModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select atleast one mode")]
    public int  optionselected { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult validation()
{
    var validation = new ValidationModel();
    validation.options = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Add or Update Customer", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Update Customer Credit", Value = "2"}
    };
    return View(validation);
```

**View :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Validation", "home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.optionselected, Model.options, "Select List")

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.optionselected)

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />     
}
```

Here by default **select list** option will be displayed in my drop downlist. But here I want my error message to be displayed. But it is not displaying. When user select value 1 or 2 then this error message should not display.

I tried using Modelstate also in my controller but not working :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Validation()
{
    var validation = new ValidationModel();
    validation.options = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Add or Update", Value="1"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Update Customer", Value="2"}
    };
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("bill");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code blow might fulfill your expectation

```
public ActionResult validation()
{
    var validation = new ValidationModel();
    validation.options = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "-- Select one --", Value = "" },
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Add or Update Customer", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Update Customer Credit", Value = "2"}
    };
    return View(validation);
} 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Validation", "home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.optionselected, Model.options)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.optionselected)

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />     
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Still I am not getting error message for default value. When I click on OK button it is redirecting to page without showing error when I am in default option, that is Select one.

Comment: Have you included Jquery validation javascript file in your page?

Comment: Yes I did that before only. I have in my view : <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Maybe validation is not activated in your page, investigate your web.config for <appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
 </appSettings>

Comment: Hi I have this enabled in my web.config file. I checked. Seriously I am also getting confused what error I am having.

Comment: Obviously, the problem is in client-side so, maybe an java script error prevents validation mechanism to work properly. Check it by Firebug or something that is an error in your page when it is loaded.

Comment: Hi just to cross check, do we need to add <appSettings> <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> </appSettings> this key to web.config inside view folder or outside one. Now I check and got to know I dont have this in web.config inside my view folder.

Answer (score 0):

After spending long time with this stupid validation, i got to know I just had to change order of scripts in my layout.cshtml. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811816/mvc-4-client-side-validation-not-working). Bloody MVC!!!