# client side validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side-validation

My client Side Validation not working  on Update

My scripts  are in right Order...(I wrote them as per tutorial)
 
My Browser(Chrome) have javascript Enabled

Web.Config File

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Edit View :

```
@model MultipleRowsDemo.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FUllName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FUllName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FUllName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AGE)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AGE)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AGE)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HireDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HireDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HireDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salary)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonalWebSite)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonalWebSite)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonalWebSite)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlternateText)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlternateText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlternateText)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

similar posts :

> [asp.net mvc client side validation not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985782/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-not-working)
>
> [MVC 4 Client side validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811816/mvc-4-client-side-validation-not-working)

this post suggest script should be in correct order

> [jquery client side validation not working in MVC3 partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134949/jquery-client-side-validation-not-working-in-)
>   mvc3-partial-view

This problem is about partial view ... I dont have that one

Please suggest

Comment: is validation fires???

Answer (score -1):

If you have _Layout or Master Page you can keep the Script link there.